# How to get current browser url with Azure AD authentication (OWIN) : <owin.identityProviders>

Tags: sitecore-client, azure, azure-ad, owin

Currently we have the requirement like we want set redirect url as per current browser url

So for that we trying to set redirect url  custom implementation of  IdentityProvidersProcessor , but its return value as 127.0.0.1 .

as we did investigation it looks "IdentityProvidersProcessor " owin.identityProviders run before "httpBeginRequest" event, so we are not able to exact browser url .

Anyone have idea.

Any help appreciated